# How can i get json from xquery in java?

Tags: java, json, spring, xquery, basex

I want to get jsonstring in my method.
I'am trying this:

```
XQConnection conn = baseXDataSource.getConnection();
XQPreparedExpression expr = conn.prepareExpression
        ("declare option output:method 'json'; \n" +
                "<json objects=\"json\">\n" +
                "<a>asd</a>\n" +
                "</json>");

XQSequence result1 = expr.executeQuery();
result1.next();
XMLStreamReader result = result1.getSequenceAsStream();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new StAXSource(result), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
return stringWriter.toString();
```

but getting exception:

```
javax.xml.xquery.XQException: The prefix "output" is unknown in this static context.
    net.xqj.basex.bin.I.getNamespaceURI(Unknown Source)
```

If i execute xquery in basex query processor, i get

```
{
  "a":"asd"
}
```

How can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JSON conversion is not a XQuery standard feature. See  BaseX implements it as a vendor extension.
see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/ for what compliant processors must support.  JSON output is not included.

you haven't The XQuery implementation you are using.
I suggest re phrasing the question in the form of how to generate JSON using your specific XQuery processor.

the best you can do in pure XQuery is to find or write a module that transforms to Json, implemented in XQuery and output as text.